# Activity Page Token

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps-activity

I'm trying to keep track within the activities list, but the pageToken is really useless!!

Just to test, I ran this (javascript) code:

```
function Get(Url)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
}

pageToken = "";
do {
    console.log(pageToken = (x = Get("https://www.googleapis.com/appsactivity/v1/activities?\
    access_token=***ACCESSTOKEN***\
    &source=drive.google.com\
    &drive.ancestorId=0B8dK0Hw8TTYoX2pmOTZBcnlzVFE\
    &pageSize=10\
    &fields=*\
    &pageToken="+pageToken)).nextPageToken);
} while (pageToken);
```

I get the same Activities list (x) everytime, with a different and random nextPageToken. There's not following like with the Drive.Changes API.

Should I just result to using the Changes API? I've spent 2 days trying to get this working! ​

Comment: your code is kinda odd. Have another look at how XMLHttpRequest works

Comment: That's far besides the point; entirely irrelevant, in fact; as I said, I quickly wrote it to test the API.

Comment: Also, there's actually nothing wrong with the request; I've no idea what you mean. It's a basic synchronous get request. Think you should have a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests